# Download .vbs inside of xampp server instead of displaying the code

Tags: php, vbscript

We have in our company a VBS script that users need to donwload, it's pretty simple.

But, here in the SERVER we have to run another applications in PHP we are trying to put this VBS there to users download. But when they enter in the link it displays the code of VBS and don't download.

Have something I can do to fix that?

**SOLVED**

Using this link, if someone want to: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: Put the code, are you trying this using `header()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your webserver is apache, you could create a .htaccess file in the directory with the vbs files you want users to download with the following contents:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(vbs)$">
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

This will cause all vbs files in that directory to show a "save file as" dialog instead of showing the code directly in the browser.

**Alternatively**, since you mentioned PHP, you could create a new php file with the following code in the directory with the vbs file:

```
<?php
header("Content-Disposition: attachment");
readfile("yourfile.vbs");
?>
```

And then just point to the php file instead of the vbs file

Comment: Hi @Andrew! Thanks for your reply. I've tried the 2 things. So, I have here a XAMPP running APACHE. Tried to put a .htaccess file in the htdocs folder and also scripts folder where vbs is and didn't worked, still opening the vbs (XAMPP already config without module commented). The second one, download a PHP with the content of VBS. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Hey @RodrigoBRF. First of all, check the httpd.conf file in the xampp folder (c:\xampp\apache\conf in windows) and look for a line that says `AllowOverride None` and change it to `AllowOverride All` to allow htaccess to override settings (If you are using virtual hosts, you might have to do the same thing in the httpd-vhosts.conf file). Then try the htaccess solution again but this time **restart apache after creating the htaccess file**. Restarting apache is an important step that I forgot to mention.

Comment: I'm not sure if you tried the PHP solution or not but I think it should work too. Just create a php file like **download.php** with the code from my answer (replacing yourfile.vbs with the actual vbs file name) and stick it in the same directory as the vbs file. Then when you want to link to it, you would do something like `<a target="_blank" href="path/to/download.php">Download</a>`

Comment: Hi Andrew! Tried the .htaccess as you mentioned, didn't work. The PHP file I'm having the problem as I said, when you hit link to 'download.php' it downloads, but downloads a .PHP with the code of VBS inside of it, it doesn't download as a .vbs file! Look my code: <?php
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment");
 readfile("mapearimpressora.vbs");
?>

Comment: Friend, I solved it using the code in this link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php thank you so much!

Comment: Perfect. Glad I could help.